# How to ignore a json file?

Tags: git, react-native, github, gitignore

I keep my api key in a json file. This json file is in the main folder. I don't want to commit this keys file to github. What should I add to the gitignore file?

My project files are as follows..

[image]

Comment: Just the line `keys.json` should work.  Have you tried it?

Comment: @Kirill Don't I have to put any signs on it?

Comment: No, just a single line `keys.json`.  .gitignore is just a list of path patterns to ignore, one per line ([docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore))

Comment: @Kirill Thank you.I didn't know it was that simple

Comment: But be aware that if the file is already tracked (as it seems to be the case), just adding it to the `.gitignore` file is not enough. You will have to untrack it with `git rm --cached keys.json` (and commit the "deletion"/untrack of this file.

Comment: @Philippe Thank you for reply. I will consider your answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply add `keys.json` into your `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the same that sensorario said, just one more thing if you file is already in the repo you have to delete of there.